# _bstr_r vs _T("")

Tags: c#, c++, com, com-interop

I have a .net library which is registered as a COM object, when importing the .tlb file in a C++ project I'm getting such a method declaration

> ```
>   virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetBid (
>     /*[in]*/ BSTR symbol,
>     /*[out,retval]*/ double * pRetVal ) = 0;
> ```

for the .NET equivalent

```
double GetBid(string symbol);
```

now I'm trying to call it like this

```
double bid;
ptr->GetBid(_T("AAPL"), &bid);
```

which doesn't work as expected, because on the .NET side the string parameter is actually an empty string.

If I change to such a call

```
double bid;
ptr->GetBid(_bstr_t("AAPL"), &bid);
```

everything works as expected.

Why both calls are compiled fine, but the result is different? Shouldn't the first call be converted into a correct marshaling of string?

Thx for any under the hood information about BSTR magic :)

Comment: Simply, a `wchar*` C string is not a `BSTR`.

Comment: well yes, but isn't that converted by the implicit operator when I'm passing to a BSTR parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BSTR has a 32-bit length *preceeding* the string.  Thus, BSTR can contain embedded nulls.

_T("AAPL") creates a wchar_t * with a terminating null, but with no length prefix.

Under the hood though, both are wchar_t * so the call compiles and there is no conversion necessary.  You were somewhat lucky because worse things could happen than just getting no string on the other side.  The marshaler might look at the _T("AAPL") count back 32-bits, and happen to get a reeeeaally long length value by luck, which would be bad. :-)

Youl would get an automatic conversion if the parameter was defined as _bstr_t, since that would invoke the _bstr_t(wchar_t *) constructor.

Comment: I'm wondering why Visual Studio doesn't use _bstr_t when generating the header file from .tlb and uses BSTR?

Comment: It can, but it depends on what you put on the #import statement.  Did you use raw_interfaces_only?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/298h7faa.aspx

Comment: yes, I did, here is what I use #import "e:\z\ManagedChange\ManagedChange\bin\Debug\ManagedChange.dll.tlb" named_guids raw_interfaces_only

Comment: Remove raw_interfaces_only and it will generate the "wrapped" interfaces.  They are noticeably different, and much easier to work with.  But it may break your existing code since the signatures are different.  For example, instead of returning an HRESULT and having return values be [out] parameters, functions have actual return values and the HRESULT becomes an exception.  It gives you other signatures with a raw_ name, that lets you access the low-level methods.

Comment: that's much better, also the raw interfaces are generates as well, but have a prefix raw_.

Answer (score 1):

Because [BSTR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa909807.aspx) is a pointer to a wide character string, but it's not mean that you can just assign simple const wchar_t* string. For working with BSTR you need to use a few system functions, line [SysAllocString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa910561.aspx) for creating BSTR. _bstr_t class incapsulate all this stuff